# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 with android application in xamarin.android

Tags: sql-server-2008, xamarin.android

How to connect an Android application to SQL Server 2008 in Xamarin.android without using web services? If it is not possible without web services, please give me easy link from where I can create a web service. I am new to .net and Xamarin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To cooperate with sqlserver you will need a Webservice! Look at

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEAqXkeWHnw

and be aware there are different places where you host your service.

Can be a website or a local machine (self hosted service)